# Subtract rows of one table from another table

Tags: mysql, null, left-join

I have two tables in MySql which contain records something like this.

```
table-A                    table-B
---------------------      ---------------------
|prod_id  | cat_id  |      |prod_id  | cat_id  |
---------------------      ---------------------
|1        |1        |      |1        |1        |
|2        |1        |      |2        |1        |
|3        |1        |      |3        |1        |
                           |4        |1        |
                           |5        |1        |
```

Now I want to compare this two tables and my expected result is.

```
---------------------
|prod_id  | cat_id  |
---------------------
|4        |1        |
|5        |1        |
```

I have checked about 'EXPECT', 'MINUS' in sql but they do not support in MySql.

Can anybody help me? Thanks is advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP has not made any effort to attempt to solve this themselves.

Comment: This is not true I have tried joins & other sql functions but they are giving me common values not remaining values and other sql syntex not supporting in mysql so at last I put this question on Database Administrators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data in TableA

```
SELECT * FROM TableA;
+---------+--------+
| prod_id | cat_id |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |      1 |
|       2 |      1 |
|       3 |      1 |
+---------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Data in TableB

```
SELECT * FROM TableB;
+---------+--------+
| prod_id | cat_id |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |      1 |
|       2 |      1 |
|       3 |      1 |
|       4 |      1 |
|       5 |      1 |
+---------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Resultant query**

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM TableB b 
LEFT JOIN TableA a 
ON a.prod_id = b.prod_id AND a.cat_id = b.cat_id 
WHERE a.prod_id IS NULL;
+---------+--------+
| prod_id | cat_id |
+---------+--------+
|       4 |      1 |
|       5 |      1 |
+---------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29a4d/2) for same.**

Comment: You don't have to test both columns for NULLs, one is enough: `WHERE a.prod_id IS NULL ;`

Comment: Sure @ypercube, I will take care of that.